# How do i dereference some files in my git repo

Tags: git, cordova

When working on my Cordova project, I didnt have a `.gitignore` file, so when i committed everything (by way of `git add *`, it seemed to commit all my platforms, .idea, and plugins.

So, this is now pushed to GIT, but I wanted to dereference them, so they arent downloaded in the future.

I just created a new Cordova .gitignore as follows.

```js
#Cordova Info
platforms/
plugins/

# ANDROID / ECLIPSE

# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files - android project subfolder
Android/bin/
Android/gen/
Android/assets/

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# IOS / Xcode
build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
IOS/www/

# OSX
.DS_Store

# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
```

I ended up grabbing the "PhoneGap GitIgnore" and added platforms and plugins to it at the top.

*So it comes down to 'how do i unlink the platforms and plugins folders and is this a solid gitignore for Cordova 6.3.0' ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For file:

```
git rm yourFile
```

For dir:

```
git rm -R yourDir
```

Comment: By chance, do you also happen to have a decent gitignore file for Cordova?  I was looking online and wasnt sure what a good design was